# FutureBuilder is not detecting no data

Tags: flutter

I need to show a message  when no data is found in the response.I get the response like this [] when there is not data.How to handle when the future is empty.I went through many post and tried but when i try them either the error message is displayed or the data is displayed.\

```
  future: _future,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        debugPrint("HAs data");
          return ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 80,
              itemCount: myList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>DisplayReports(appointmentDetail:myList[i])));},
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical:5.0),
                    leading: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(),
                      child: Icon(Icons.date_range,color: Colors.blueGrey,)
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      myList[i].doctorName,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          myList[i].apptDateTime != null ?
                          formatDate(DateTime.parse(myList[i].apptDateTime), [
                            dd, '/', M,'/',yyyy]) : " ",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          softWrap: false,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black54,),
                        ),                
                      ],
                    ),
                    trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),onPressed: (){},),
                  ),
                );
                return LinearProgressIndicator();
              });

    },
```

Comment: what is myList and where are you using snapshot ? please add all details which are related to this.

Comment: myList is the list that i get from the api which is loaded in the initState(),and i haven't used snapshot anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by checking how much elements is in list.

i hope following code help you.

```
future: _future,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        debugPrint("HAs data");
           // here check is length of data is 0 then return specific widget which you want to return as i demonstrate with text widget.
          if(myList.length==0){
             return Text("You have not data");
          }
          return ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 80,
              itemCount: myList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
```